# Creating unread message count on tab widget and fragments in android

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-fragments

I have an Application where in i am creating tabs as shown below.

[image]

The application is created for 2.2 and above versions. I have used fragments for android 3.0+ and tab widget for 2.x versions. I have used the android support.v4 jar file for compatability for below 3.0 versions. Check this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html)

Now, I want to display count for unread messsages as shown in the image below.

[image]

I am not able to create the unread count on the tab widget.

**Questions:** 
How to create the count on the tab widget for 2.x versions.
How to create the count on the fragments for 3.x and above versions.
Is it possible to create a relative layout with a text view and add it to the tab widget?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @PrasnjitDey  Have you found any solution ?

Answer (score -2):

You might want to have a look at this:

[Android ViewBadger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)